# Assign value to child object and handle list object values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First please start from picture i have attached the json output view. On picture you will see i was able to assign value only to the root level objects but on child level i failed to assign value properly which i need. My main goal is get output exactly like Json code bellow. How can i fix my controller to get exactly example json type output from JavaScriptSerializer?

[image: pic]

Controller:

```
 var root = new RootObject();
            root.name = "Jan Kowalski";
            root.email = "jan.kowalski@wp.pl";
            root.dayOfCycle = "10";
            //root.tags.Add(new Tag
            //{
            //    tagId = "Xw",
            //});
            //root.scoring = 25;
            //root.customFieldValues.Add(new CustomFieldValue
            //{
            //    customFieldId = "n",
            //    //value = "white", value should be list
            //});
            root.ipAddress = "89.206.36.193";
            var camp = new Campaign(); 
            camp.campaignId = "jf7e3jn";

            var jsBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(root);
```

Model class:

```
public class Campaign
        {
            public string campaignId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tag
        {
            public string tagId { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomFieldValue
        {
            public string customFieldId { get; set; }
            public List<string> value { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string dayOfCycle { get; set; }
            public Campaign campaign { get; set; }
            public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
            public int scoring { get; set; }
            public List<CustomFieldValue> customFieldValues { get; set; }
            public string ipAddress { get; set; }
        }
```

Json body i want from JavaScriptSerializer:

```
{
    "name": "Jan Kowalski",
    "email": "jan.kowalski@wp.pl",
    "dayOfCycle": "10",
    "campaign": {
        "campaignId": "jf7e3jn"
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "tagId": "Xw"
        },
        {
            "tagId": "Nn"
        }
    ],
    "scoring": 25,
    "customFieldValues": [
        {
            "customFieldId": "n",
            "value": [
                "white"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ipAddress": "89.206.36.193"
}
```

Comment: How does it look like when you uncomment the commented lines in your controller? (Also, of course, before calling `Add` on `root.tags` etc., you need to create List instance, e.g. `root.tags = new List<Tag>();` else you'll get a reference exception but I guess you know that)

Comment: Also missing: `root.campaign = camp;` just before creation of `jsBody`...

Comment: Yes above comments was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented already, for the sake of completeness:

1. Missing: `root.campaign = camp;` just before creation of `jsBody`
2. Missing `root.tags = new List<Tag>();` to prevent Null Reference Exception, just before `root.tags.Add` is executed